# Should it be "staggered at" or "staggered by"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I'm trying to say that the linguists were "astounded at his progress":

> The eminent linguists who were teaching him were **staggered by** his
>   remarkable progress. They were the ones learning from him before long,
>   so it was only natural.

Also, should it be "staggered by" or "staggered at"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage [is correct](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stagger) (definition 2a: *to overwhelm with emotion or astonishment*), and [both](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/staggered) *staggered by* and *staggered at* seem to be correct.

Comment: In my experience, "staggered *by*" is vastly more common than "staggered *at*".

Comment: @Martha According to [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=staggered+by%2Cstaggered+at&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), *at* is at a historical low: about a quarter as often as *by*. "Vastly" more common is perhaps an exaggeration.